Does the HTML/JavaScript standard guarantee .click()ing elements that are not appened to the DOM?
In some solutions to "trigger file downloads with JavaScript" questions, the pattern
link = document.createElement('a')
link.click()

is used.
In various places, people report that this did not work in Firefox, suggesting that you need document.body.appendChild(link); first:

Download File Using JavaScript/jQuery
document.createElement('a').click() not working in firefox

It does work in my Firefox 125 which is newer than those answers.
Do the HTML/DOM/JavaScript specs prescribe that .click() needs to work even without appending to the DOM?
(Bonus points for anybody who can find the commit in Firefox that made this work.)

DOM specifications don't have anything to do with JavaScript specifications, really.

And the DOM spec does seem to treat .click() as a special case for legacy reasons.
